401 status code - Axios get api react native only on ios
I am calling the GET API through axios request. And also I am sending the bearer token on header. The API is working fine on Android. But, it is throwing 401 status code only on iOS device and also for only one api this is happening.

are you sending like this with Bearer? headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`} or headers: {'Authorization': `${user.token}`}?

I am sending like this  Authorization: Bearer ${token.access},

Any solution to solve this issue?

Yes, the issue is with ending slash (/) on the endpoint. Make sure you defined the API endpoint exactly the same as the REST
